# LotFP Combining Power for Summon

Tags: spells, summoning, lamentations-of-the-flame-princess, retro-clones

I have a bit of a fascination with the [lamentations-of-the-flame-princess](/questions/tagged/lamentations-of-the-flame-princess) *summon* spell (Grindhouse *Rules & Magic* p142). I am wondering if there are any rules or guidelines for combining HD of summoners?

I would think *summon* is a case where combined power would be the norm, if a powerful creature is to be summoned by those foolish enough to try. This combination could be a coven of magic-users, or a group of cultists. Using *The Devil Rides Out* (Wheatley, 1934) as a bit of an example, Mocato (a powerful magic-user) is able to summon the [Goat of Mendes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baphomet), which would certainly be an arch-fiend. There is a mob of cultists, many of which are likely 0-level in game terms. There is very little in the way of sacrifice (possibly an animal, but I do not recall from the book or film). Mocato *might* be powerful enough to summon it solo, but would also be smart enough to stack the deck in his favor as much as possible for the inevitable Domination roll. Also of note, this summoning occurred on [an unholy day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walpurgis_Night).

Notes on sacrifice from p143 of Grindhouse *Rules & Magic*:

> Each full 2HD of sacrifices gives the caster a +1 bonus to the Domination roll, or 1 HD for a +1 bonus if the sacrifice is the same race as the caster.

So, the question is are there LotFP rules concerning combining power in lieu of sacrifice, and from what source? I have looked through the Grindhouse *Rules & Magic* and the free Magic book, but may be searching for the wrong term. This question assumes that there is a single spell caster, who knows the *summon* spell. Perhaps there is something similar to "every 4HD of cultists or every two levels of magic-user participating in the summons (apart from the caster) provide +1 to the Domination roll"?

Comment: Hi Darius, I've removed part of the end of your request because it was requesting and inviting answers which are almost certainly untenable under our quality requirements. However [our homebrew policy](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5153/is-homebrew-an-acceptable-answer-to-a-question) already permits people to provide tried-and-tested expert-based homebrew guidance if they judge it's worthwhile.

Comment: Cool, I appreciate the fix and being cool about it.

Answer (score 4):

Magic in Lamentations of the Flame Princess is more personalized, chaotic, and disruptive than other, D&D-adjacent games.  There's no general way to combine the efforts of Magic-Users.

The in-game approach to get a combined Magic-User version of a particular spell, such as *Summon*, would be research, as suggest by the most recent magic supplement:

> ### [Vaginas Are Magic!](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/214470/Vaginas-are-Magic), page 6
>
> If a caster wants to use these spells without the specific restriction, she can recover a spellbook with the spell in it and research her own version without the restriction. Spell research rules aren’t just there to fill out a page count.

Comment: I added the sacrifice rule from the spell to the question as a reference. The question has more to with with substitution of combined power for sacrifice vicrims. It seems natural that 13 magic-users (with one doing the actual casting) working in a combined effort would provide some bonus to Domination without shedding their blood. It is likely not equal to human sacrifice in potency, but leading a group of mages or a throng of cultists is a show of power. I'll add some of this to the question, as this comment is running on a bit.